# Aurelia e2e: text.indexOf() not correctly comparing string to that contained in a div

Tags: node.js, protractor, automated-tests, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm trying to check to see if text contained in a div header matches what I have inside in my text.indexOf() function and if it does, it will print 'true' on the console and if not, it will print 'false'. 
I don't want to check if the text is an exact match, I just want to see if "EUR" is contained inside in the Div.
Here is the code from my page object file

```js
this.checkIfEur = function(eur) {
     var checkCurrency = element(by.className("m-l-sm"));
        checkCurrency.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text.indexOf("EUR">= 0))   {
              console.log("true");
            }
            else if (text.indexOf("EUR"<= 0)){
              console.log("false");
            }
          });
};
```

```html
<div class="currencies">
               <span>Opening Currency</span>
               <span class="m-l-sm">
               <b>EUR 1,000</b>
               </span><span class="m-l-sm">`
               <b>GBP 5,000</b>
               </span><!--anchor-->
        </div>
```

The problem is that if I was to replace `EUR` with `zzzzzzz` the console will still print 'true'. It doesn't seem to matter what I text I want to be accepted, it will always print true.

I'm possibly doing this completely wrong, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (text.indexOf("EUR">= 0))
```

Should be (notice the position of closing parents)

```
if (text.indexOf("EUR")>= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, if you want to check if "EUR" is in a string and you are using this

```
if (text.indexOf("EUR") >= 0)   {
    console.log("true");
} else if (text.indexOf("EUR") <= 0){
    console.log("false");
}
```

you can better use this

```
if (text.indexOf("EUR") > -1)   {
    console.log("true");
} else{
    console.log("false");
}
```

or if you only want to log the result, you can do this

```
console.log("Found EUR in string:", text.indexOf("EUR") > -1);
```

, see also the examples of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, pleasing to know I was on the right track, frustrating that it was caused by something so small!